# Alternate proof of Cauchy Schwarz

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

My teacher gave me the following simple proof of CS inequality:

Consider 2 vector $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ in an N dimensional space
$\mathbf A = \sum_{i=0}^n{a_i \mathbf x_i}$

And $\mathbf B = \sum_{i=0}^n{b_i \mathbf x_i}$

Where $\mathbf x_i$ are unit vectors

Now the magnitude of dot product must be less than or equal to the product of the magnitude of the two vectors and equality holds iff they are parallel

But I haven't found this proof in many books so is there any flaw with it?

Comment: A claim is not a proof. This claim is precisely the statement of CS theorem (and the introduction about the dimension and the unit vectors is useless)

Comment: You are assuming what you are trying to prove. Although its not always directly stated this way, Cauchy Schwarz says that "the magnitude of dot product must be less than or equal to the product of the magnitude of the two vectors."

Comment: But the dot product is the product of magnitude multiplied by cosine of the angle between them and cosine is less than 1 with proves the claim for dot product

Comment: @AarushSaharan Sure, so if you can prove that dot product = magnitude * magnitude * cost(angle)  then you've proved the CS theorem for vectors in Euclidean space.

Comment: "the dot product is the product of magnitude multiplied by cosine of the angle between them" requires proof.

Comment: Is that not how dot product is defined?

Comment: @AarushSaharan nope. Its defined as $a_1 b_1 + \cdots + a_n b_n$. More to the point, what you need to show is that $a_1 b_1 \times \cdots \times a_n b_n = |A| \cdot |B| \cdot cos(\theta)$. If you can do that, you've proved CS for vectors in Euclidean space.

Comment: @roundsquare $+$, not $\times$

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, good catch. I've fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Ok now I get it. But then although we have proved that dot product is less than the product of magnitudes, how do we show that it is product of magnitude multiplied by cosine of angle between them

Comment: @roundsquare you fixed only a half.

Comment: @AnneBauval oddly, it won't let me edit it anymore. Weird.... Hopefully anyone who stumbles on this isn't confused or, if they are, reads the rest of these comments.

Comment: @AarushSaharan this will be a (partial) definition of this angle.

Comment: @AarushSaharan If you want to define $\cos(\theta)$ using the "unit circle" definition, you can:
1. Show that the dot product is invariant under rotation (relatively simple).
2. Show that for any $2$ vectors, there is always a rotation in $\Bbb R^n$ that maps them into $\Bbb R^2$, and one of them lying on the $x$-axis (a bit less simple).
3. Compute.

PS. Here we assume that length is invariant under rotations (we can't use the dot product to define length here, so I guess we have to go with the $2$-Hausdorff measure), which implies that angles are also invariant under rotations.